# Search All Attribute in one textbox

Tags: php, yii, yii2

[image] 
I have a table: Email, and the attributes: id, subject, content, to, cc, ...

Then in the index, there is only one search box. I want this search-box can search all value in each attribute.

Like this picture above, we can search by "To" attribute, or "Subject" attribute or other attributes in 1 search textbox.

[image]
[image]

Should i code in the controller or in the index view?

I hope all of you can share the code, so can complete this task.

Thank you and have a great day

Comment: please explain what exactly you try ?

Comment: It would be nice to see what it was that you tried in order to have resolved this yourself, which would have shown us that you did research this before posting the question. When you try, you also learn. If someone just gives you an answer/solution, it would have all been for nothing and I say this for the/your future. You can then edit your post to contain something that may have failed; even that shows an effort on your part. Remember, we're always glad to help :-)

Comment: Thank you, i am sorry about that :)

Comment: Too broad. There are a number of both frontend and backend components involved in this, and it is unclear exactly where the actual problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After search value filtered in following fields
if $search variable is empty then orFilterWhere function ignore that condition in query

```
$model = User::find() 
$model
->orFilterWhere(['like', 'name', $search])
->orFilterWhere(['like', 'email', $search])
->orFilterWhere(['like', 'address', $search])
->asArray()
->all();
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to add an explanation of how your code works and how it solves the OP's problem. Many SO posters are newbies and will not understand the code you have posted.

Answer (score 2):

Another way,

```
$model = User::find()
    ->where([
        'OR',
        ['like', 'name', $search],
        ['like', 'email', $search],
        ['like', 'address', $search],   
    ])
    ->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it. In Yii, Yii2, You can do somethings like:

```
<?php
    $model = User::find()
    ->where('name LIKE :name', [':name' => $search])
    ->orWhere('email LIKE :email', [':primary_user' => $search])
    ->orWhere('address LIKE :address', [':address' => $search])
    . . .
    ->all();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer sir, but where i put this piece of code?  in the controller? or index? or where?

Comment: Ah yeah, need to put this in a function in Controller. Make a route for it, and need to render it. See more informations on Documentation page: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en